# Referencing Python "import" assemblies when calling from IronPython in C#

Tags: asp.net, python, ironpython

I'm a complete noob when it comes to IronPython. I need to call a py script from an ASP.NET website, and have the following code:

```
var ipy = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\python\test.py"));
test.DoWork();
```

The version of IronPython I'm using is 2.7.

The 3rd party python file I need to call has the following import directives:

```
import sys
from array import *
from subprocess import *
```

I'm receiving the error "No module named subprocess". I've copied the subprocess.py file from the IronPython installation Lib directory, but I assume I need to link to it in the C# code?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I found the solution:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine();

var sp = scriptEngine.GetSearchPaths();
sp.Add(Server.MapPath(@"~\python\lib"));
scriptEngine.SetSearchPaths(sp);

var scope = scriptEngine.Runtime.ExecuteFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\python\test.py"));
```

If anyone has any comments/improvements please feel free to elaborate seeing as I'm in new ground with all this Python/IronPython malarky.

Comment: Just a note: you could also do this from within the Python script if you wanted to, by [modifying `sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#inst-search-path). Also, you may want to post your solution as an answer and accept it, instead of keeping it in the question body itself.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. I tried to post it as an answer but as I'm a new user I was unable to for 8 hours. I'm having a new issue now attempting to pass in arguments...

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way of doing this:

```
dynamic sys = scriptEngine.ImportModule("sys");            
sys.path.append(somePath);
```